# ASP.NET MVC Web application vs ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Other than the fact that **ASP.NET MVC Web Application** has more clarity in its implementation of the MVC pattern and that it strictly follows the MVC pattern, how is it different from **ASP.NET Web Application**?

If you make your **ASP.NET Web Application** have a **Business Logic Layer**, **Data Access Layer** and strictly make all data queries using them, then does'nt it completely follow the **MVC pattern**?

My logic here is: the BLL & DLL together is the **Model**, the ASPX page is the **View** and the code-behind (ASPX.CS) page is the **Controller**.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can confirm the above and/or shed more light on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recent question may address your concerns: [How does the MVC pattern differ, if at all, from the DAL / BLL design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267924/how-does-the-mvc-pattern-differ-if-at-all-from-the-dal-bll-design-pattern)

Comment: Glad to help. I've been following the MVC questions, as I am very interested in evaluating it, as you are.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a bit more experience, discipline and work to design an ASP.NET MVP Web Application so that your application supports test automation. When you can slap an advanced GridView onto a page along with a SqlDataSource and bind it directly to a stored procedure you throw your test automation out the window.

A lot of MVP applications are written using 3rd party toolkits that encapsulate a lot of the  codebehind logic. That tends to muck up your clean separation of responsibilities in a MVP design.

On the plus side I can write an ASP.NET Web Application with a rich UI using a 3rd party toolkit in a 10th of the time I can with MVC in it's current state. For a simple admin tool that's exactly what I would do today. For a large scale n-tier application I would lean towards MVC.