# Visual Studio 2010 : Web Projects

Tags: .net, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC Web application vs ASP.NET Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276211/asp-net-mvc-web-application-vs-asp-net-web-application)

As i'm new to ASP.net I want to ask a general question.
Which are the main diffrences between :

- ASP.net Web Application
- ASP.net MVC 2 Web Application

And when to use each one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend MVC.

You should consider starting with some of the information available from Microsoft: http://www.asp.net/get-started

> [WEB FORMS (aka Web Application)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)
>
> Offers a familiar model that lets you reuse controls and incorporate
>   data into your Web site, making your work reusable and you more
>   productive.
>
> [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
>
> Builds on a pattern that enables clean separation of concerns within
>   your web applications, and delivers full control over HTML for
>   enjoyable, agile development.
>
> HOW DO I CHOOSE? [Watch a 5 Minute Introduction Video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/choosing-the-right-programming-model)
>
> Visual Studio Express or WebMatrix ... how do I choose? Here's our
>   quick guide to choosing the right technology for your needs. You can
>   install everything or grab just what you want. This short video breaks
>   it down so you can pick the right technology and get right to building
>   great websites.

Comment: I wanted to have an old ASP.net developer's point of view.
I'll try to begin by MVC.
Thank you.