# ASP.NET MVC project architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

I am pretty *confused* about the **ASP.NET MVC** project architecture. 
In ASP.NET WebForm I am normally for small to medium size project using following Project pattern

**DAL <-- communicate through *DTO/reader/dataset* -- > BL <--> UI**

I think in MVC application should be like

**DAL <-- communicate through *DTO/reader/dataset* --> BL *is Model* <--controller --> UI *is View***

```
        OR
```

**DAL <--communicate through *DTO/reader/dataset*--> BL <-- communicate through *Model* --> controller <--> UI is *View***

where Model is some business object

I would appreciate if anybody would be able to (including **Jeff** maker of *[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)*) give any production level experience with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comparing traditional 3 tier **ASP.NET Web App** to **ASP.NET MVC**, the following becomes the corresponding elements:

**Business Logic Layer** and **Data Access Layer** together is the **Model**

**ASPX** file is the **View**

**Code-behind** (ASPX.CS) is the **Controller**

Have a look at these links for more discussion on the same topic on SO:

[ASP.NET MVC Web application vs ASP.NET Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276211/asp-net-mvc-web-application-vs-asp-net-web-application)

[How does the MVC pattern differ, if at all, from the DAL / BLL design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267924/how-does-the-mvc-pattern-differ-if-at-all-from-the-dal-bll-design-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

I've already started to a ASP.Net MVC project. In my architecture, layers almost like yours.

There is an Entity Layer corresponds to your Data Access Layer and Business Layer as a separated project to easy to plug to another project in corresponds to your Business Layer. And there are Modal Layer accessors in Modal part of the MVC application.

[Here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/mvc_Overview.htm) is a reference from Asp.Net Mvc Documentation that gives a little advice of application structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother to create your architecture from scratch,  you should consider using [Neos-SDI MVC4 Template](http://www.mvctemplate.com), it would be a very good start. It's a template for visual Studio 2010 and 2012, the website will help you to install and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Nido Framework](https://nidoframework.codeplex.com/)

Nido is a code framework (a common project, architectural pattern) written on .NET framework 4.0, Entity framework 6.0 and few other additional libraries to encourage you (we developers) to develop our systems adhering to good architectural disciplines.

link: https://nidoframework.codeplex.com/